# Converting query code from jQuery to Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

Given is the following jQuery code which I try to remove and convert into standard JS code:

```
$('.switch').click(()=>{
    $([".light [class*='-light']", ".dark [class*='-dark']"]).each((i,ele)=>{
        $(ele).toggleClass('bg-light bg-dark')
        $(ele).toggleClass('text-light text-dark')
        $(ele).toggleClass('navbar-light navbar-dark')
    })
    $('body').toggleClass('light dark')
})
```

This is what I came up with:

```
for (let s of [".light [class*='-light']", ".dark [class*='-dark']"]) {
  document.querySelectorAll(s).forEach((element, index) => {
    element.classList.toggle('bg-light bg-dark')
    element.classList.toggle('text-light text-dark')
    element.classList.toggle('navbar-light navbar-dark')
  })
}
document.querySelector("body").classList.toggle('light dark');
```

But I receive the error message:

> Failed to execute 'toggle' on 'DOMTokenList': The token provided
> ('light dark') contains HTML space characters, which are not valid
> in tokens

Can anyone see anything whats wrong with this or my other "newer" code? I am new to Vanilla JS. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `toggle` want only one class at a time:

```
['light', 'dark'].forEach(el => document.querySelector("body").classList.toggle(el));
```